# Create and write in a file in c++

Tags: c++, file

I want to create a file and write something inside. so I wrote this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    ofstream m;
    m.open("bonjour.txt");
    m << "bonjour.\n";
    m.close();
    return 0;
}
```

And I think that this is correct, but when I execute it, I find no file bonjour.txt.
Have I done something wrong?

Comment: Have you checked the directory in which your program is located?

Comment: yes, And I though maybe he is confused, so I tested now putting a hole path, and it doesn't work too

Comment: Do you have "create file" permission in the current directory?  Try checking the `fail()` bit on your stream (before closing) to see if anything went wrong.

Comment: `if (m.fail()) cerr << "Writing failed.\n";`

Comment: Ok, now narrow down when it became failed.  Is it failed right after `open()`.  Also check `errno` (`perror()` function is useful for that).  Probably you are getting "access denied".

Comment: @BenVoigt, I don't know if that's how I had to write it but I wrote         cout<<strerror(errno)<<endl; and it said "no such file or directory". I read that m.open will create this file

Comment: @Ekica: It won't create directories.  Maybe you passed a directory that doesn't exist, so the file can't be created.  You could also try passing the mode `ios_base::out` explicitly.  Are you making a new file or overwriting one already there?

Comment: @BenVoigt It's working now, I think I had to put the hole path

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code that i can see, paths and filenames are not a part of the language and thus are platform independent, just remember on linux pathnames use `forward slash` and on windows, if you use a full pathname you must use the `backslash` twice like this `c:\\f\\stuff`, when you don't specify a filename usually the file is created in the directory the program was in.

Answer (score 0):

There is no issue with the code.
It works for me and file "bonjour.txt" created with content "bonjour".

Answer (score 0):

```
ofstream m("bonjour.txt", ios_base::app);
```

with the use of the append mode you can open and close your file as many times as you want and it won't erase the content that was in the text file previously.
This is reference to the ios_base::openmodes http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios_base/openmode/